# is there a way to add firebase project options within flutter app start

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase

i would simply to know how to add Firebase project options within the app
because every client will have its own Firebase project on flutter android / ios if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can pass all configuration data to the [call to `Firebase.initializeApp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios#initialize-firebase), you can get those values from anywhere you like and pass them. So you can indeed request this information from your user's in some form, and pass it to Firebase after that.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the project has the google-services.json from the related Firebase Console Projects, then its connected.

You could simply perform it too with [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/)